# Which aws sdk to use?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I want to use dynamodb SDK for nodejs. Which SDK is it, may someone please send a link to the current api? I thought this link showed the most current:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html

But according to

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/UPGRADING.md

Anything using the .Client attributes are old. I am confused which is the most current. For example should I use dynamodb.get or dynamodb.getItem to get items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the github, you should be using below link for DynamoDB -

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html

There is a tutorial as well to get started with the new dynamoDB SDK -

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx1OVH5LUZAFC6T/Announcing-the-Amazon-DynamoDB-Document-Client-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript